# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue with spark-submit

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am running pyspark job

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g  --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g job.py
```

I tried changing multiple options but every time i am getting below error:

## OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000072324e000, 985616384, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.

## Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 985616384 bytes for committing reserved memory.

## An error report file with more information is saved as:

I am new to spark can some one help me out what should be the solution with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try reducing the driver memory - the node where you're submitting the job is running out of RAM.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that might be the case?